# Why i can't allocate queue when unpack data and how to do it right?

Tags: system-verilog

I'm trying to unpack packed message of fixed format. But i can't to do it correctly, because, when compiler (irun) find the queue, it unpack all rest data to queue. 
  When i'm trying to allocate the queue, i've got error. How to unpack packed message correctly? May be it need to use various method?
Here is my code:

```
class packet;
  byte bytestream[$] ;
  byte start = 8'h11, stop = 8'h99;
  rand byte data[$];
  rand byte length ;

  constraint length_c { length inside {[3:6]}; data.size() == length; }

  task pack();
        if (!randomize())$finish;
        bytestream = { >> {start,length,data,stop}};
        $display("PACKED_PACKET @: start=%h; length=%h; data=%p; stop=%h;",start,length,data,stop);
  endtask // pack

  task unpack();
        { >> {start,length,data,stop}} = bytestream ;
        $display("UNPACKED_PACKET @: start=%h; length=%h; data=%p; stop=%h;",start,length,data,stop);
  endtask // unpack
endclass

packet p = new ;

module tb_uvm;      
   initial
     begin 
        $display("Start test");
         p.pack();
         p.unpack();
        $display("END test");
     end 
endmodule
```

Comment: FYI, a variable `length` is missing in `unpack()` method

Comment: I'm add it, but it isn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a tool issue, the code you provided works fine with VCS and Riviera-PRO when I tried it on [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/).

Your tool may be missing support for the streaming operator, so you'll just need to do the packing/unpacking the old way in separate steps.

Comment: Thank you, kolmone. It's really work's on VCS and Riviera. But not work's on cadence ncsim. I'll be carefully with it in future.